# How do we symbolize the following sentence using logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The square-root of 5 is irrational. [ 5: the number five; x · y: the product of x and y; I(x): x is a nonzero integer]

I tried to form some logical equivalences and identities, but they seemed to be incorrect.

Comment: The good members that help people like us prefer, rightly, that we include in our questions some of our effort / attempts to answer the question ourselves. It also benefits us because sometimes they expose an error in our thinking that enhances our thought process more than simply getting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can also express your sentence as "There is no rational number, whose square is five". This yields the following expression:
$$\neg\exists a, b \in \mathbb Z: I(b) \land \left(\frac ab\right)^2 = 5$$
Rearranging a bit to use only your terms, we have
$$\neg\exists a, b: (I(a) \lor a = 0) \land I(b) \land a\cdot a = 5\cdot b\cdot b$$
Although this does not allow negative rational Numbers since you didn't give a symbol for that. Of course, since technically speaking the square root of a number always has to be positive, the expression remains correct.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure quite what you're after, but one symbolization is:

$$\neg \exists n \in \mathbb Q : n\times n = 5$$

Read aloud, this is: "There does not exist a number $n$ in $Q$ (rational numbers) such that $n$ times $n$ equals $5$."